# starting an .exe file from c++ in windows

Tags: c++

I try to start an  a program from my code in c++ Visual studio. 
I tried those cmds:

```
system( "\" C:/Program Files (x86)/scilab-5.3.3/bin/WScilex.exe\"");
system( "start" C:/Program Files (x86)/scilab-5.3.3/bin/WScilex.exe\"");
system( "\" C:\\Program "" Files""(x86)\\scilab-5.3.3\\bin\\WScilex.exe"");
```

none of them worked, has anybody an Idea how to get this done 
thanks in advance

Comment: i think hemendra's answer is easy and correct !

Answer (score 2):

Use the canonical `ShellExecute` WinAPI function. The simplest case:

```
ShellExecute(hwnd, "open", "c:\\MyProgramPath\\WScilex.exe", NULL, NULL, 0);
```

For more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776886(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks I used "Cheers and hth. - Alf" suggestion, it pretty short

Comment: P.S. don't forget to accept the correct answer to your question(s)!

Answer (score 2):

Do not try to use quotes twice, as you do in Command Prompt (cmd). In a c++ code you won't need to specify it in quotes if you have 'spaces' in the file path.

You should use 'WinExec' instead of 'system', so console window will not be shown.

e.g.

```
WinExec("C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe",0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `system` function passes the string as a command to the system's default command interpreter, in Windows [cmd.exe].

So, simply don't have an extraneous space at the start of the command:

```
system( "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/scilab-5.3.3/bin/WScilex.exe\"" );
```

The [cmd.exe] command interpreter is happy with the forward slashes in the path.

---

Your first attempt:

```
system( "\" C:/Program Files (x86)/scilab-5.3.3/bin/WScilex.exe\"");
```

↑ Has an extraneous space at the start. The space matters because the command string is quoted. But you need the quotes because the path contains a space.

Your second attempt:

```
system( "start" C:/Program Files (x86)/scilab-5.3.3/bin/WScilex.exe\"");
```

↑ Should not compile. This is **not real code**. At least not code that you have successfully compiled and run.

Your third attempt:

```
system( "\" C:\\Program "" Files""(x86)\\scilab-5.3.3\\bin\\WScilex.exe"");
```

↑ Has an extraneous space at the start. The space matters because the command string is quoted. But you need the quotes because the path contains a space.